# Import CSV files in Nuxt.js framework for processing by D3

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I am trying to integrate a D3 chart into the Nuxt framework (am very new to Nuxt) and a problem I have run into is how to make a number of CSV files available to the DOM to be graphed by D3.  IN D3 this is a simple call to the CSV function:

```
 d3.csv('myData.csv, function (error, myData) {
    if (error) throw error }
```

Performing this simple function in the Nuxt.js framework is proving to be hard work (for me). First I tried to load them using the d3.csv function in the `mounted:` section of the script:

```
<script>
  import * as d3 from 'd3'
  export default {
    mounted () { 
      d3.csv('myData.csv, function (error, myData) {
         if (error) throw error }
      }
    }
</script>
```

but neither the variable `myData` or `this.myData` is available to the DOM when loaded this way.  I guess because that loads afterwards?

It seems like the Vuex store might do the job but for the life of me I cannot find the right syntax for loading the CSV and ensuring that the program waits for the CSV file to be loaded.

Is there a canonical way to load data files like this in Nuxt? Even better if someone could point to an example of something similar that I might learn from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grateful to [Sebastian Kolinks](https://github.com/sebastianks) for providing the answer.  The problem was that the `d3.csv` function was stealing the context from Vue.js, overwriting `this` with its own version.

```
d3.csv('myData.csv', function (myData) {
  this.myArray = freqData  // throws "this" is undefined error
})
```

By using an arrow function which doesn't have its own `this`, the problem was solved.

```
d3.csv('myData.csv', (myData) => {
    this.myArray = freqData   
  })
```

Sebastian's example code is at https://jsfiddle.net/L6osr9ve/